# Use Azure AD user credentials to map file storage share as network drive

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-files, azure-storage-files

Expected result: the user can map a file storage created in Azure using his/her own credentials
Actual result: the users can only use the storage name + key provided by Azure

Basically I have created the file storage, then created the file share and I managed to authenticate and map the file storage as network drive on my windows10 laptop, but I had to use the given key and username as password/login.

Is there a way to force using your own credentials? so that I can allow only members of a specific group to be part of that file storage?

ps: I don't have Microsoft Intune so I cannot just deploy the network drive automatically based on the device/user

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-faq):

> Does Azure Files Azure Active Directory Domain Services (Azure AD DS) Authentication support SMB access using Azure AD credentials from devices joined to or registered with Azure AD?
>
> No, this scenario is not supported.

Instead, use machines joined to Azure ADDS or on-prem ADDS with AzureAD Connect as per [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-active-directory-overview#supported-scenarios).